# How to catch number into InnerException C#

Tags: c#

How is possible catch number in InnerException ?
I want sort my error exception by this number. I am loking for something like

```
catch (Exception e) when (e.Number == 1000)
{
    throw new ApplicationException("IP of database is wrong);
}
```

(attached picLinks for better imagine)
https://ibb.co/dgnBav

**EDIT**

In general I want sort expections by some specific number of error exception so if you know how can I get this number it will good solution

Comment: What is the type of InnerException?

Comment: You could ``catch (Exception e) { try{ throw e.InnerExcption}catch(Something innerEx) when (innerEx.Number == 1000) }`` OR ``when ((e.InnerExcption as Something)?.Number == 1000)``, btw dont forget that your Image Shows the number -1000 and not (positive)1000

Comment: When `(innerEx.Number == 1000)` throw new exception

Comment: It shouldnt throw an excption it shouldnt compile since the base type Excption doesnt have a member called Number, you have to cast it to what ever exception type you get.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "connection request timed out" error message looks like it's used by Oracle's .NET client library: `Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException`.

We can use the `as` operator to safely check the `Number` property:

```
using Oracle.DataAccess.Client;

...

catch( Exception ex ) when ( (ex.InnerException as OracleException)?.Number == 1000 )
{
    // stuff
}
```

This can be made more readable with a static helper function and the `is-expression` introduced in C# 7.0:

```
private static Boolean CheckOracleException(Exception ex, Int32 oracleErrorNumber)
{
    if( ex.InnerException is OracleException oEx )
    {
        return oEx.Number == oracleErrorNumber;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Used like so:

```
catch( Exception ex ) when ( CheckOracleException( ex, 1000 ) )
{
    OracleException oEx = (OracleException )ex.InnerException;

    // do stuff
}
```

Comment: Why not derive his own Exception type?

Comment: @RomanoZumbé Can you clarify what you mean? I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: @Dai I guess he means instead of catch (Exception ex) why not catch (OracleExcpetion ex)

Comment: @RandRandom Because in the OP's attached screenshot the `OracleException` was the `InnerException` value, not the top-level exception value.

Comment: Can I also use  `using Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client;` ?